# How can I get tuple type from object with array of keys

Tags: typescript, variadic-tuple-types

With function which returns values from object with some list of keys from the object like below.

```
function mapObjToArray(obj, keys) {
    return keys.map(key => obj[key])
}

const result = mapObjToArray({ A: "a", B: "b", C: 'c', X: 'x'}, ['A', 'B'])
```

I want get exact type of result value, I mean `["a", "b"]` in this case, but, with code below, type of result is `("a" | "b" | "c" | "x")[]` instead of `["a", "b"]`.

```
function mapObjToArray<T>(obj: T, keys: (keyof T)[]) {
    return keys.map(key => obj[key])
}

const result = mapObjToArray({ A: "a", B: "b", C: 'c', X: 'x'} as const, ['A', 'B'])
```

I may advanced little with Variadic Tuple Type and I got...

```
function mapObjToArrayWithVariadicTuple<T, X extends [...(keyof T)[]]>(obj: T, keys: X): [...T[X[number]][]] {
    return keys.map(key => obj[key])
}

const resultVariadicTuple = mapObjToArrayWithVariadicTuple({ A: "a", B: "b", C: 'c', X: 'x'} as const, ['A', 'B'])
```

Getting closer, but still, typeof resultVariadicTuple is not I wanted `("a" | "b")[]`

Is there any way to get the result type I want???

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDyAjAVgFTgEEAnE1ATwB58A+ACjjwC5F8AaRAawFMKBnVvV4U4wNgEoA2gF0JiAN4AoRKsQkeUECSQj+AOjTphfRAF5aiJriki5SgL5KlEBPyjqe-EABsPZlAwcAmIySnoFRCJWACJUGM4AIVjsBMQAYVYAcggszgANbIAPLIdEVH5EVzB3TiksojzELMSs+wB6ACpOlU7EKAp0HitxDW8-RBhK+jiYxAAfRBjUhaWIOcWYopjpGUmaqB5UABMRxClZzmWYmV7251BIWARArDxCUnIKAHUYKAALABqqBIMBOMAg+BA6B8PBoBUQPCKhzAx0qUn0mJMonE+F2MgY1lYHG4fEEiHyElYGMx+Ck+SkYBAyGwPBIMhksj2yjUni0OlJAkMGGx5ks1lsfHsThcbg8Y18UGBoPBkOhsPMr2CHzCPz+QJBYOOEKhMJ4ESisXiSRSaUyzVyBWKpXKlWqtXODSaLTaEiUXR6iD6AHNNLAwMGqj44Pw2fp+oMeGJPOMlYbVaaNVNEDN4qtrrt9u4jqdkxdrUtUrcg+0gA)

Comment: @tom10271 While that's true, I think we can assume for the purposes of the question that the value (and type) being passed in is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sure thing is that both `obj` and `keys` parameters must be `const`.
Otherwise, as types in TypeScript are detached from the runtime, the returned type is undeterminable.

If this requirement can be assumed, then something like this should be the answer:

```
type _Map<
  K extends readonly any[],
  O extends { [key in K[number]]: any }
> = K extends readonly []
  ? []
  : K extends readonly [infer H, ...infer T]
  ? [O[H], ..._Map<T, O>]
  : never;

function mapObjToArray<
  K extends readonly (string | number | symbol)[],
  O extends { [key in K[number]]: any }
>(obj: O, keys: K): _Map<K, O> {
  return keys.map((key: K[number]) => obj[key]) as any;
}

const result = mapObjToArray(
  { A: "a", B: "b", C: "c", X: "x" } as const,
  ["A", "B"] as const
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is where the magic happens
type Tobj<O> = {
  [key in keyof O]: [key, O[key]];
};
type ObjectToTuple<O> = Tobj<O>[keyof Tobj<O>];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


const test = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: 1
} as const;

type T = typeof test;

type TupleT = ObjectToTuple<T>;

(Object.entries(test) as TupleT[]).map((entry) => {
  switch(entry[0]){
    case "a":{
      return entry[1] === "a"; // TRUE!
    }
    case "b":{
      return entry[1] === "b"; // TRUE!
    }
    case "c":{
      return entry[1] === 1; // TRUE!
    }
  }
});
```

Note that you still have to cast the array because typescript cannot guarantee you that the object doesn't have more attributes than the one listed in the type